# How can i model upward natural convection in various angles (0 - 90)?

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I am looking for a way to numerically solve the Naiver-Stokes equations for steady incompressible flow using FDM over a surface with various angles?

Comment: Have you done a google search? What have you found, and why don't the things you found satisfy your needs?